# Microsoft word 2007 default styles don't print well how to fix the problem?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

Microsoft word 2007 default styles for heading 1, heading 2, heading 3 are in a nice blue color which looks great on the screen but when I print the document it comes out not so nice because my printer tries to dither the colored heading I have a black and white laser. Is there some way to tell word to make the default style headings be black for printing purposes but stay colored for screen usage.

Answer (score 1):

To change the fonts that appear in blue in Word 2007/10 do the following:
Home Ribbon - Styles group - change styles - Style set - then place a tick against Default Black and White.  The blue fonts will not show as black.

To make this permanent you can change the blank/normal template by following the above.